# How to fill <textarea> with text?

Tags: javascript, textarea, getelementbyid

im trying to fill with text following textarea:

```
<textarea aria-invalid="false" class="form-control" rows="5" id="domains" name="domains" placeholder="" style="text-align: left;"></textarea>
```

I tryed following codes but nothing worked for me, am i missing something?

```
content.document.getElementsByName("domains")[0].value = "TESTING";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("domains").innerHTML="TESTING";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("domains").value = "TESTING";
```

If it help i can post wesite link with this textarea i want to fill

Thanks, Peter

Comment: Your third example works.

Comment: your 2nd & 3rd example must work, check if the color of the `textarea` makes the text invisible. Set it to some other color with CSS

Comment: The first one would work if you remove `content.` and the other do work as shown. Do you see any error messages in the console of your browser?

Answer (score -1):

You can use This Code .

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textareaTest");
textarea.value = "Hello World!";
```

```html
<textarea name="textareaTest" id="textareaTest" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can define the content with innerHTML like this :

```
 document.getElementsByName('domains')[0].innerHTML = 'TESTING'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).